# Is it possible to change the SQL Server errorlog file number on Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux

Everything is in the title. We can change the number of errorlog files using the registry on Windows, does anybody know if it is possible on Linux? I see no mssql-conf option for this.

Thanks

Comment: Does SSMS not present this setting for Linux flavors of SQL Server? Under Object Explorer, select an instance. Then under Management, right-click on SQL Server Logs, select Configure, and look on the General page.

Comment: there is no Configure option in SSMS when connected to SQL Server on Linux

Comment: Take a look at this: https://blog.dbi-services.com/sql-server-on-linux-and-logging/ Perhaps the log viewing capabilities on Linux make it unnecessary to split the log into separate pieces.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment, even on CTP 3.1 of SQL Server 2019 as I write this.

As you've discovered, it requires changing a registry setting, and trying to run `xp_instance_regwrite` results in the following error:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
>
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Bob Ward's book *Pro SQL Server on Linux* doesn't mention anything either. It refers to `filelocation.errorlogfile` for setting the **path** using `mssql-conf`, but not the number of files.

If I were to hazard a guess, this will eventually find its way into the product, but it is not there now.

Answer (score 0):

I see now an option in mssql-conf

> ./mssql-conf set errorlog.numerrorlogs

So that might be new, and the answer to my question.